# Dynamically unregister/remove intent from activity intent filter

Tags: android

Is it possible to dynamically unregister an intent that was registered with an activity's intent filter in its manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. It sounds like you should be registering your filter in code if it's not a permanent thing.

Comment: Well, I had registered my app in the manifest for action.MAIN, category.LAUNCHER, and category.DEFAULT in order to replace the HOME screen, but I want to retain the ability restore the default HOME screen dynamically.  I can't seem to get a regular broadcast receiver to handle replacing the HOME screen the way the manifest-defined filter did.

Comment: Umm. I'm pretty sure you shouldn't do what you're asking. Let the user replace the homescreen if they want.

Comment: And umm, Im pretty sure those aren't the intents needed to replace the homescreen. Mayb I'm wrong, but action.MAIN and category.launcher are just what put your icon on the homescreen.

Comment: Whoops - I meant android.intent.category.HOME, not LAUNCHER.  And there's only one person dumb enough to install an app I wrote and that's me, so I would be the only user.